# Sencha Touch: How to fit an Ext.Panel's toolbar to content?

Tags: sencha-touch, ext-panel

I have an `Ext.Panel` with a `'toolbar'` that will hold a variable amount of content in a `<div>` that I want to ensure is large enough to contain all content. Is there a way to dynamically size the toolbar to fit its content?

When I add, say, multiple lines to the `<div>`, they are cut off. The `layout: 'fit'` property keeps it contained relative to the parent container, but how do I expand it to contain all child content?

The toolbar is defined in a panel as follows (it is then added to a `'card'` Panel layout).

```
    var panelTitle = 'Old McStopher's Panel'
    this.listpanel = new Ext.Panel({
        title: panelTitle,
        items: this.list,
        layout: 'fit',
        dockedItems: {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            html: '<div class="statsTpl">Old McStopher's Content</div>',
            title: panelTitle
        }
    });
```

I'm using SASS/SCSS. Is there a recommended way to do so with such? Or is there some property to set for the toolbar itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the answer as of right now is to simply remove the `xtype: 'toolbar'`. The title does not show, but this is not an issue, as the `<div>` will have all needed content (including a title, if need be). Because the content is still in dockedItems, it still docks to the top and does not scroll like the `this.list` content. So, one can debate if this is technically fitting a "toolbar", but the end result of dynamically fitting the top content is achieved.

Comment: I realize this, but if you are looking to use the title parameter you might as well just use a toolbar with a different layout config. Either way though as I said earlier a toolbar and container / panel are practically the same thing except for some default parameters being set for you like the layout: 'hbox'.

Comment: Thanks, @Ballsacian. I shall give yours a go (and update the chosen answer, as necessary) when I return to that portion. Best.

Answer (score 1):

`Ext.Toolbar` inherits directly form Ext.Container and because of this has layout options. If you give you toolbar a different layout like `autocontainer` or `fit` you should be able to get the `title` attribute to work while having your expanding toolbar.